# AdControl exception

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to add an `AdControl` to my XAML page but it just fails.

I'm not posting any code because I simply dragged it from the toolbox and dropped it on my page.

The exception thrown says

> TypeInitializationException

and then, whatching the `InnerException`, it says

> ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name:"native Object"

(I'm translating it from Italian so the message may not be exactly this way).

I've googled a little bit but it seems that nobody had this kind of error before.

Is there any chance that I ran into a bug?

Comment: If you create a new project from scratch and try to add the control to that project, does it work?

Comment: It works with an empty project, still not working in my app even if I have added all the required capabilities.

Comment: Then there's something wrong with your app. It's going to be hard to debug with that little information

Comment: Actually, this works just on the empty project. I've tried with another app that I'm developing and I've got the same problem. Please tell me if you need some information

Comment: If you can upload somewhere a project demonstrating the issue (be it one of your app or a sample project) then I can have a look, but otherwise there isn't much I can do... You can try looking at the callstack of the exception, it might provide additional information

Answer (score 0):

If you create UWP project, please install [Microsoft Store Services SDK](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/229b7858-2c6a-4073-886e-cbb79e851211) firstly. If you create windows and windows phone 8.x, please install  [Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows and windows Phone 8.x](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb4b3020-9b56-4e81-a314-e40cff00fb52). The following example is for UWP.

1.In Visual Studio, open your project or create a new project.

2.If your project targets **Any CPU**, update your project to use an architecture-specific build output (for example, **x86**). If your project targets **Any CPU**, you will not be able to successfully add a reference to the Microsoft advertising library in the following steps. Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows and windows Phnon 8.x

3.From the Solution Explorer window, right click **References**, and select **Add Reference…**

4.In **Reference Manager**, select one of the following references depending on your project type:

For a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) project: Expand **Universal Windows**, click **Extensions**, and then select the check box next to Microsoft Advertising SDK for XAML (Version 10.0).

strong text For a Windows 8.1 project: Expand **Windows 8.1**, click **Extensions**, and then select the check box next to **Ad Mediator SDK for Windows 8.1 XAML**. This option will add both the Microsoft advertising and ad mediator libraries to your project, but you can ignore the ad mediator libraries.

For a Windows Phone 8.1 project: Expand **Windows Phone 8.1**, click **Extensions**, and then select the check box next to **Ad Mediator SDK for Windows Phone 8.1 XAML**. This option will add both the Microsoft advertising and ad mediator libraries to your project, but you can ignore the ad mediator libraries.
[image]
5.In **Reference Manager**, click OK.

6.The complete code for the MainPage.xaml file should look like this.

```
<Page
x:Class="MyAdFundedWindows10AppXAML.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MyAdFundedWindows10AppXAML"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:UI="using:Microsoft.Advertising.WinRT.UI"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

</Grid>
```

More information you can refer to [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/adcontrol-in-xaml-and--net)